# Как мне выравнять айтемы

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: Скриншот по больше][image: Выровнять их под один уровень]

Конкретная проблема у меня с адаптивной версткой

```
/* Обертка */

.team__inner {
    margin: 0 30px 0;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

/* Айтемы */

.team__item {
    flex-basis: 20%;
    max-height: 50%;
    overflow: hidden
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Чтобы все блоки были в один уровень

Comment: Разделяй на заголовок, тело с текстом и иконки снизу

Comment: Какими командами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логика следующая:

У Вас есть блока с представителями компании, в этом блоке контент можно условно разбить на:

1. Изображение
2. ФИО
3. Должность
4. Описание

Каждый из вышеуказанных блоков рекомендую описывать отдельным классом (.photo, .fio, .position, .description)

Последнем блоку можно задать фиксированную высоту, исходя из Ваших потребностей, а свойством overlofw:hidden можно скрыть "непомещающийся контент".

Кроме того, адаптивная вёрстка в Вашем случае подразумевает изменение положения блоков с .team__item, на мобильных устройствах "друг под другом" (в 1 колонку, обратите на этой внимание). 4 блока "в строку" на мобильном устройстве не соответствует принципам адаптивной вёрстки.

Comment: Хорошо, если 4 блока в строку не соответствуют принципам адаптивной верстки. Как мне правильно их сверстать?

Comment: Вы правильно сверстали для экраном с брейкпоинтом md, lg. Вам нужно описать логику для устройств с брейкпоинтами xs и sm (если проводить параллель с bootstrap).
Ознакомьтесь с media запросами, особенно рекомендую в Вашем случае поиграться с bootstrap, более менее приводит мысли в порядок в отношении адаптивности.

Comment: Мне не нравиться bootstrap технология, буду использовать grid

Comment: вы можете использоваться всё что угодно, понятия это не меняет) нравится вам css grid - пожалуйста, grid в данном контексте - инструмент для вёрстки, сетка, а не какая-то конкретная "технология" (условно).
В части развития - рекомендую всё таки изучить bootstrap, полезный набор инструментов, особенно flex.

Comment: Спасибо, очень полезно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй для родителя

```
align-items: center
```

Comment: У них появляются отступы сверху и снизу так что это не вариант

Comment: Тогда немного непонятно как ты хочешь что бы это выглядело. У тебя разный контент в колонках. 
Скинь скрин побольше с тем что выше

Comment: Обновил, это часть адаптивной верстки